# Why can I not see any content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anybody tell me why I can not see the text under my navbar. Is it hiding it? I have set the navbar as fixed. Is this the issue?

I am trying to add a header underneath but I can't even see the text.

Thanks in advance

Reece

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- LINKS TO EXTERNAL FILES (BELOW) -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slyderesp.css">

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- NAVBAR (RESPONSIVE) -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Slyde</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#meet">Meet The Band</a></li>
            <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#videos">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<!--HEADER (RESPONSIVE)-->

    <div>WHY CANT I SEE THIS?</div>











<!--LINK TO EXTERNAL FILES (BELOW) -->
<script type="text/javaScript" src="js/slyderesp.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
 <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your navbar has the class `.navbar-fixed-top` which makes it fixed in the browser window. Your `<div>` is just below it. Remove that class or add some padding to your body.